# I don't know how to use NSMutablearray correctly. Can you help me?

Tags: objective-c, integer, nsmutablearray

I am making a quiz app. Here is a part of my code:

```
-(void)getQuestion:(int)randomvalue{

    if (Stufe == 1) {
            iD = arc4random() % 50 + 1000;
        }
        if (Stufe == 2) {
            iD = arc4random() % 56 + 2000;
        }
        if (Stufe == 3) {
            iD = arc4random() % 52 + 3000;
        }

NSString *Abfrage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT frage FROM questions WHERE id = %d", iD];
```

I am working with sqlite3 and with the iD I got my question from my database. Now how can save the iD in a NSMutableArray and how I can check firstly whether the iD exists in my NSMutableArray? So that the App don't ask the same question. (Stufe is difficulty and unimportant).

Thanks

Comment: Two hints:  1) Look at the documentation for NSMutableArray.  2) You can only store Objective-C objects in an NSArray, so you must "enclose" the number in an NSNumber object.

Comment: 3) Don't start variable names with capital letters.

Comment: 4) Don't build queries using `stringWithFormat:`. Properly bind in the values using the proper methods/functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conversion from int to NSNumber**

iD is currently an `int`. You will need to convert it to an `NSNumber` object before it can be stored within an `NSMutableArray`. You can do this with `numberWithInt`.

```
NSNumber* iDNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:iD];
```

**Creating an NSMutableArray containing the NSNumber**

Once you have the `NSNumber`, you can create an `NSMutableArray` with `arrayWithObjects`.

```
NSMutableArray *iDArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:iDNumber, nil];
```

**Adding an NSNumber to an existing NSMutableArray**

You can add the item to an existing `NSMutableArray` with `addObject`.

```
[iDArray addObject: iDNumber];
```

**Checking if an NSNumber already exists in an NSMutableArray**

To check if the array already contains the object, you can use `containsObject`.

```
if (![iDArray containsObject: iDNumber])
{
    [iDArray addObject: iDNumber];
}
```

**Conversion from NSNumber to int**

If you want to use an `NSNumber` as an `int` later, you will need to convert it back using `intValue`.

```
int iDInt = [iDNumber intValue];
```